# Smartsheet - How to attach a file to a row using Smartsheet API and PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

The smartsheet api docs provide this documentation to attach a file to a row.

> ```
> curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/rows/{rowId}/attachments
> ```
>
> \
>       -H "Authorization: Bearer ll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05" \
>       -H "Content-Type: application/msword" \
>       -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ProgressReport.docx"' \
>       -H "Content-Length: FILE_SIZE" \
>       -X POST \
>       --data-binary @ProgressReport.docx

*How do I translate this into the appropriate calls to a curl session in php?*

I assume that I need to create a header block such as

```
$headersAttachment = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $AccessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/pdf",
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mydoc.pdf"', // **is this for just the filename or the full path?**
    "Content-Length: " . $FileSizeOfMyDoc 
);
```

and use it like so

```
$curlSession = curl_init($rowsURL . '/' . $rowId . '/attachments');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersAttachment);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
$getSheetResponseData = curl_exec($curlSession);
```

*What do I need to put in $body so that the data from the file is uploaded?*

The smartsheet api docs say

> The following example request shows a simple upload that adds a file
>   attachment to a sheet:
>
> POST
>   https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/4509093797881732/attachments
>   Authorization: Bearer ll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05 Content-Disposition:
>   attachment; filename="ProgressReport.docx" Content-Type:
>   application/msword Content-Length: 5463
>
> < Binary content for file >
>
> As shown in this example, the contents of the file is included in the
>   body of the POST request. In most programming languages, this is done
>   by reading the file from an input stream and writing it out to the
>   output stream of the HTTP request.

**this is done by reading the file from an input stream and writing it out to the output stream of the HTTP request.** *<--- How Do I Do This In PHP?*

As an after thought, how can I check this with Postman?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

While Smartsheet does not have a PHP SDK, you are essentially using a secondary language to send REST commands and JSON over the wire.

You'll need the following headers:

```html
POST /2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/rows/{rowId}/attachments
Host: api.smartsheet.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=binary
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=“Image.jpeg"
Content-Length: 1048945
Authorization: Bearer TOKENHERE
```

I believe you can put the path in your filename param if you need to.  And the file size is in bytes.

Comment: Although this helps It does not address the issue of how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Postman had the answer all the time. Postman has an option to generate code snippets, which up to now I had not read correctly, as I was fixated on CURL. I then noticed on the left hand side there was an option for PHP - cURL which gave me the answer I wanted. Using this code finally worked for me.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/SHEETID/rows/ROWID/columns/COLUMNID/cellimages",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<file contents here>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN",
    "Content-Type: image/png",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"modify.png\"",
    "Content-Length: <file size here>
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```